# Gradle: run 2 Jar tasks at one time make only one jar file

Tags: java, gradle

I create 2 Jar tasks in Gradle. One for common classes:

```
tasks.register('compile-common', JavaCompile) {
    description = 'compile common classes'
    source = sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs.collect { it.toPath().resolve('my/artifact/common').toFile() }
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = project.buildDir.toPath().resolve('classes.common').toFile()
}

tasks.register('common-jar', Jar) {
    description = 'build common jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Build': project.version
    }
    archivesBaseName = project.name + '-common'
    from project.buildDir.toPath().resolve('classes.common').toFile()
    dependsOn 'compile-common'
}
```

And for complete project with custom name:

```
tasks.register('project-jar', Jar) {
    description = 'build project jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Build': project.version
    }
    archivesBaseName = project.name
    from sourceSets.main.output
    dependsOn 'compileScala'
}
```

After this I run build in bash:

```
$ rm -rf build/libs; ./gradlew project-jar common-jar; ls -l build/libs
-rw-r--r--  1 a.iatsuk  staff  265619 Dec 24 14:52 project-common-0.3.61.jar

$ rm -rf build/libs; ./gradlew common-jar project-jar ; ls -l build/libs
-rw-r--r--@ 1 a.iatsuk  staff  11482514 Dec 24 14:53 project-0.3.61.jar

$ rm -rf build/libs; ./gradlew common-jar; ./gradlew project-jar; ls -l build/libs
-rw-r--r-- 1 a.iatsuk  staff  11482514 Dec 24 14:54 project-0.3.61.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 a.iatsuk  staff  265619   Dec 24 14:54 project-common-0.3.61.jar
```

Why I can't get 2 jars when I call both tasks? I try wrote release task, but it not works anyway:

```
tasks.register('build-release') {
    dependsOn 'common-jar'
    dependsOn 'project-jar'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove all `=` symbols and replace `archivesBaseName` by `baseName`. I don't know why, but this fix helps me:

```
tasks.register('common-jar', Jar) {
    description 'build common jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Build': project.version
    }
    baseName project.name + '-common'
    from {
        project.buildDir.toPath().resolve('classes.common').toFile()
    }
    dependsOn 'compile-common'
}

tasks.register('project-jar', Jar) {
    description 'build project jar'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Build': project.version
    }
    baseName project.name
    from {
        sourceSets.main.output
    }
    dependsOn 'compileScala'
}
```